# String pattern printing

Tags: java, string

How to print a string like below?

> S
>   St
>   Str
>   Stri
>   String

I have tried this, but I don't know how to proceed after this:

```
String s = "string";

for (int i = 1; i <= s.length(); i++)
{
    System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

using substring?

```
String s="stringyyyyiyi";

for(int i=1;i<=s.length();i++)
{

   System.out.println(s.substring(0,i));
}
```

Comment: No problem :-) just add tag of java.